# WPF, Blend triggers in UserControl and DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, silverlight

Can anybody explain me difference between using UserControl and DataTemplate when I use Expression Blend interactivity triggers in WPF:

When i use trigger in DataTemplate - color does not become yellow:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type WpfApplication5:C1}">
    <Grid>
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <Core:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=PctChange}" Comparison="GreaterThan" Value="0.5">
                <Core:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
            </Core:DataTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

but when i copy grid into UserControl - trigger work:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type WpfApplication5:C1}">
    <WpfApplication5:GridUserControl />
</DataTemplate>
```

Is this behavior bug or feature of Blend triggers?

PS. PctChange in all cases more than 0.5.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It has something to do with namescopes. Because you haven't specified the `TargetObject` on `ChangePropertyAction` it changes the property on the root element in the name scope, which is in the first case the `DataTemplate`. In case with a user control, the root element in the scope is the user control and its background is changed.

Comment: With TargetObject does not work. ChangePropertyAction changes background of Grid not UserControl, but it only work when i copy grid with triggers into UserControl

Comment: How do you know that it actually does change the background of Grid if you don't see it?

Comment: It changes background when i copy grid into UserControl

Comment: What I'm saying is that maybe it actually changes the background of the user control itself (not grid) in this case.

Comment: no. when i set background for UserControl and Margin for Grid. it changes background only for grid.  <UserControl ........ Background="Red">
    <Grid Margin="50" x:Name="xxxxx">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <Core:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=PctChange}" Comparison="GreaterThan" Value="0.5">
                <Core:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{x:Reference xxxxx}" PropertyName="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
            </Core:DataTrigger>

Comment: I've just created a simple project to reproduce your problem. But everything seems to work just fine. Probably the problem with something else.

Comment: Hm, When i use DataTemplates and create object DataContext = new C1() { PctChange = 4.5}; - background color does not changes, but when i update PctChange on button click - it changes. I think that problem - with applying triggers on template applying.